# Why v != null ? v++ : 1 is not the same as (v != null ? v : 0) + 1 on incrementing a key on HashMap.compute?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I want to apply a compute method that increment value if key exists, otherwise puts 1. Having

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I don't understand why

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) map.compute(1, (k, v) -> v != null ? v++ : 1);
```

results in `{1=1}`
and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) map.compute(1, (k, v) -> (v != null ? v : 0) + 1);
```

results in `{1=10}`?

My understanding on first case is:

- if there's a value with key `k`, get the result from `v++` and put it back, else fill it with 1

While the seconds case is:

- if there's a value with k `k` save `v+1` instead, else save `0+1`, which is also 1

Why in this case running `v++` doesn't result in `v+1`?

Comment: It is same as `int res = v++;` `res` will be `v` and `v` will be incremented afterwards

Comment: you should use `v + 1` instead of `v++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `(k, v) -> (v != null) ? v++ : 1` will always return 1 after the first iteration.

On the first iteration, `v != null` will evaluate to false and `1` will be mapped to key `1`. On all subsequent calls, the condition will be true and `v++` will be used, with the fact that post-increment `v++` being in use, `1` will be the new mapped value all the time (and not 2).

`v++` increments the local parameter of the lambda expression, NOT the value in the map (remember, [Java is pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5761558))

If you use **`++v` instead of `v++`**, you'll get 10 too. This will work because the new mapped value is already incremented (unlike `v++` which takes the value and *then* increments `v`)

`(v != null ? v : 0) + 1`, on the other hand, will always add `1` to the currently mapped value (it doesn't suffer from the behavior of `v++`)

Comment: Well, even simpler is `map.merge(key, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);` or `map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);`